# Получить указатель на новый элемент вектора c++

Tags: c++, vector

Насколько я понял, при добавлении элемента в вектор через emplace_back, он станет на свободное место (т.е. был элемент, его удалили, вот и свободное место) или же в конец вектора.
Вопрос: как получить указатель на только что добавленный элемент вектора?

Comment: А что будет, если стереть элемент через erase? Место "освободится" же.
Вот в таком то случае .back() и не поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вас интересует именно указатель на добавленный элемент, а не итератор, то вы можете его получить, допустим, следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> v;

    v.emplace_back( int( 'A' ), 'A' );

    auto p = &v.back();

    std::cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
65: A
```

Ежели вы используете метод `insert` вместо одного из методов всавки в конец вектора, то метод `insert` возвращает итератор на вставленный элемент. Поэтому вы можете получить указатель на элемент, используя этот итератор. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };

    auto it = v.insert( std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), 4 ), 3 );

    int *p = &*it;

    std::cout << *it << "\t" << *p << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
3   3
```

В программе для обращения к вставленному элементу используется как итератор, так и указатель.

Также так как вы можете обращаться к элементам вектора, используя оператор индексации, то вы всегда можете получить указатель на любой элемент, зная его индекс. например,

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int *p = &v[2];
```

Имейте в виду, что когда элемент вектора удаляется, то все элементы, стоящие за удаляемым элементом, сдвигаются к началу вектора, занимая место удаленного элемента, если только удаленный элемент не был последним элементом вектора.
То есть элементы вектора всегда располагаются последовательно друг за другом в непрерывном участке памяти. Никаких "дыр" в векторе не бывает.

Если вам надо вставлять элементы в середину вектора, то лучше будет использовать `std::deque`, или если прямой доступ к элементам не нужен, то `std::list`.

Comment: Мне нужно добавлять элемент в вектор. Просто добавлять, позицию я ему указать не могу, insert не подойдет. В том то и дело, что после erase список не схлопнется и новый элемент добавится не в конец.

Comment: @rinart73  Смотрите мой обновленный ответ. После удаления элемента, стоящие за ним другие элементы перемещаются к началу вектора. Никаких "дыр" в векторе не бывает.

Comment: А какие есть списки, которые так не делают? Мне кажется, это не слишком производительно выходит. Да и если указатель на память, а оно все сдвинулось, то неудобно.

Comment: @rinart73, посмотрите на двусвязные списки (list), если вам не нужен произвольный доступ по индексу. Если же нужен - то тут только деревья.

Comment: @rinart73 Вы можете использовать std::list, если вам надо часто добавлять элементы в середину вектора. В крайнем случае вы можете использовать std:;deque.

Comment: Мне нужен доступ по указателю на область памяти.

Comment: @rinart73 Я вам показал, как получить указатель на произвольный элемент вектора.

Comment: А в deque и list это сработает? Доступ по указателю на только что добавленный элемент?

Comment: @rinart73  Это и векторе работает. В чем проблема?

Comment: В производительности. Схлопывание после удаления элемента не устраивает.

Comment: @rinart73 Используйте по крайней мере тогда std::deque.

Answer (score 1):

В векторе нет "свободных мест", в нем есть только непрерывная последовательность элементов.

`emplace_back` (как и `push_back`) добавляет элемент в конец вектора.
После `v.emplace_back()` добавленный элемент будет в конце вектора, и ссылку на его можно получить вызвав `v.back()`. Соответственно выражение `&v.back()` выдает указатель.

Comment: А при удалении элемента через erase? Я не думаю, что весь вектор после удаления пересортируется для закрытия стертого элемента.

Comment: Зря вы не думаете - потому что именно так `erase` в векторе и работает.

Answer (score 0):

Если добавлен в конец:

```
&v.back();
```